# how to make external monitor primary (xubuntu)

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, panel, monitor

I am using Xubuntu 12.04 and I want to use my 24" monitor as a secondary display. Ok!

First Try: Going to the Settings Manager --> display and searched for the secondary display to enable it. But there is no secondary display entry. okay..no luck.

Second Try: Starting the Nvidia-settings manager and try to configure the displays here. This way it works, but I am not able to make the external screen primary. The funny thing is: i can only make the external monitor primary if it is configured to be positioned at the left side of the notebook display :P But i need it the other way around. (notebook display left, external (primary) monitor right) If i configure it that way the top panel is automatically placed on the notebook display.

Third Try: Disper: My last trywas to use disper to configure my display layout. But the same problem appears. i used the command: `disper -d DFP-1,DFP-0 -t left` but the panel again stays on the wrong screen. if i use `disper -d DFP-1,DFP-0 -t right` it works...

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the programme ArandR. It is a simple graphical programme ideally suited for Xubuntu. I have been using it without problems for two monitors at home and at work. It even allows me to save custom configurations, so I can easily switch between different set-ups.

It is available through the Ubuntu Software Centre.